# Blackberry: limit app to portrait mode

Tags: blackberry

I've tried this piece of code in my UiApplication class, but I get an illegalstatexception.

```
Ui.getUiEngineInstance().setAcceptableDirections(Display.DIRECTION_PORTRAIT);
```

I dont want my app to change its orientation. I want it to stay in portrait mode.

EDIT:

How it is used:

```
public class HelloWorld extends UiApplication {


    public static void main(String[] args){

        Ui.getUiEngineInstance().setAcceptableDirections(Display.DIRECTION_PORTRAIT);


        HelloWorld theapp = new HelloWorld();
        theapp.enterEventDispatcher();

    }


    public HelloWorld(){

        pushScreen(new FeaturedScreen());

    }


}
```

Comment: Are you using this before invoking UiApplication.pushScreen()

Answer (score 3):

```
DemoClass() 
{
     int direction = Display.DIRECTION_PORTRAIT;
     Ui.getUiEngineInstance().setAcceptableDirections(direction);
     pushScreen(new AppScreen(this));        
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DemoClass app1 = new DemoClass();                       
    app1.enterEventDispatcher();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class HelloWorld extends UiApplication {
   public static void main(String[] args){
       UiEngineInstance ui = Ui.getUiEngineInstance();//I have added this new line in your code
       ui.setAcceptableDirections(Display.DIRECTION_NORTH);
       HelloWorld theapp = new HelloWorld();
       theapp.enterEventDispatcher();
   }

   public HelloWorld(){
    pushScreen(new FeaturedScreen());
   }
}
```